# Having trouble with outer joins/sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In MSSQL

I have a table which lists tournaments a golfer has fields season, tournament, player, position

e.g

```
season  tournament  player  position
-------------------------------------
1983    A           Mr Par  20  
1983    B           Mr Par  1  
1983    C           Mr Par  1  
1984    A           Mr Par  17  
1984    B           Mr Par  2  
1985    A           Mr Par  1  
1985    C           Mr Par  8
```

I want to create a query in MSSQL which will just show me the wins by year, inc where he did not win at all

i.e.

```
season  player  numWins
------------------------
1983    Mr Par  2  
1984    Mr Par  0  
1985    Mr Par  1
```

Can't seem to get correct result but know it is out there somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  SELECT season, player, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN tour_position = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WINS
    FROM your_table
GROUP BY season, player
ORDER BY season, player
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT [Season], COUNT(*)
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE [Position] = 1
GROUP BY [Season]
```

Comment: Oops, missed the "inc where he did not win at all" requirement. Adam Bernier seems to have the right answer though.